# PUT failing on OKHTTP

Tags: android, rest, http, android-studio, okhttp

I am using okHTTP in Android to make a PUT request. I Have added the headers and I have added .put request. But somehow the request is not going through. I have used Log entries to trace that.  The code goes like:

String url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/v1.0/xxxxxx/" + xxxxxxx;

```
 JSONObject jSon = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jSon.put("prescription_interval_id", prescriptionIntervalId);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    jSon.put("prescription_auto_refill", false);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String data = jSon.toString();

                MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, data);


                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .addHeader("Authorization", token)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .put(body)
                        .build();

                //

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                        Log.d("FAIL","CALL FAILED");
                        Log.d("Request",request.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                        Log.d("Response",response.toString());
                        Log.d("SUCCESS","CALL SUCCEEDED");
                    }
                });
```

The request is not being made. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried calling `client.newCall(request).execute()` rather than `enqueue()` to see if the connection is being made correctly?

Comment: It would probably also be helpful to check the response code to see what it is that is failing with the request.

Comment: protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Accidentally i was putting a space in between url end points! works fine now :)